# why does one of my applications keep changin pid?

Tags: iis, iis-7

Hi i got this strange thing happening to me and im to novice to solve it myself. Im doing some test at work and i got this one application pool that keeps changing its PID a couple of times a day, i notied this two days ago when i could not access it and started to look for erros. it works for a couple of hours and it changes and i have to restart the application pool and the site itself for it to work again.

I been using the basic settings as i do on the 4 other sites we got up and running, and they work good. anybody know why it keeps changing its PID? i got the feeling like its "rebooting" or something in that nature.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the PID changes, it means a new process has been started.

Turn on all the Recycling logging options in the Recycling properties for the App Pool.

If you right-click and Recycle the Application Pool after it's failed, it'll probably start working again.

App pools will self-terminate:

- every 29 hours
- after 20 minutes of idle time

by default, configurable from the Recycling... or Advanced Settings dialogs.

If you look at the System and/or Application event logs in Server Manager under Diagnostics -> Windows Logs, you'll see whether IIS (or WAS specifically) is upset with the processes, and the reason why.

Otherwise; fix the app.

Comment: yes recycle works. if i set the idle timeout to 0 then its "off" so to speak right? can i change the serf-terminate 29 hour span?

Comment: Yes, and yes you can in the Recycling settings, but if it's happening twice a day you're not hitting the 29 hour timeout yet.